# ngCordova Barcode Scanner viewport - Ionic

Tags: barcode, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner, ngcordova

I followed the instructions in: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/

And works fine.

The problem is that the viewport is rather small and I cannot read LONG CODE 128 barcodes (50+ digits). Is there a way to change the size of the viewport (and the text?)

Thanks,